# Get a APK file work on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, android

How do I get a APK file that is the android app of Square POS to open and work properly on a Windows 7 PC?

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Please provide more information about *what* APK you are trying to get working on Windows 7 and what functionality you expect from it. It may not be possible. If it *is* possible, you would need to run a virtual machine for Android...

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Would Oracle Virtual Box work to open the file?

Comment: https://superuser.com/tags/bluestacks/info

Comment: You will need an **Android emulator**. However, whether that will help will depend on the app and what you want to do. For example, even with an emulator you will probably not be able to use the barcode scanning feature.

Comment: What best safe ones are there?

Comment: [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/) is a very popular Android *emulator*, but an emulator will not allow you to connect peripherals (USB or bluetooth) to any apps running in them.* A virtual machine *can* use devices connected to the host computer, so it may be necessary if you need to connect the app to Square's peripheral devices. VirtualBox, HyperV, VMWare are all equally useful for this purpose. (* -- *Can anyone recommend an emulator that does connect to devices on the host?*)

Comment: @Romen How would I connect it to virtual box?

Comment: *What* do you want to connect to virtual box? Are you using one of Square's magstripe or card readers?

Comment: It's the APK file.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me: Do you need to use any of Square's [peripheral devices](https://squareup.com/us/en/hardware) with the APK? (If the answer is no, you do not need a virtual machine. My original comment forgot to mention emulators, which are useful if you only need the software to work.)

Comment: Yes I would need Square's peripheral devices?

Comment: OK... *which ones*?

Comment: No I wouldn't need Square's peripheral devices. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Then use [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/) is an emulator for Android that allows you to run Android apps (APK files) on Windows.

That should be all you need if you only require the app itself, and no connectivity to Square's [peripheral devices](https://squareup.com/us/en/hardware).

In regards to whether it is safe,
A moderator of Reddit's [/r/bluestacks](https://www.reddit.com/r/BlueStacks) subreddit has asserted that [the software comes with signed certificates and does not include any other bundled software](https://www.reddit.com/r/BlueStacks/comments/97iszr/is_bluestacks_safe/e48t31n/). You can trust the software as much as you trust the company [Bluestack Systems Inc.](https://www.bluestacks.com/about-us.html) itself.
That comment does also highlight that there are risks that may come from running some Android apps due to those apps containing malicious code; This is not something that Bluestacks can control and the user must be responsible about what software they run within Bluestacks. (If you were using an actual Android device the same risks would apply.)